# Inverse matrix of sin and cos being multiplied.

Tags: matrices

find the inverse
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 5 e^{2 t} \sin(2 t) & 5 e^{3 t} \cos(2 t)\\
-6 e^{2 t} \cos(2 t)& 6 e^{3 t} \sin(2 t)
\end{pmatrix}$$

I understand the inverse of

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos(t) & -\sin(t) \\
\sin(t) &  \cos(t) \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$

being

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
 \cos(t) & \sin(t) \\
-\sin(t) & \cos(t) \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$

But not am confused with the extra parts.

so would my set up be
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\sin(t) & -\cos(t) \\
\cos(t) &  \sin(t) \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward thing would be to apply the formula $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}.$$

If you want to use the inverse you already know, you can think of your matrix $A$ as the product $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\sin 2t & \cos 2t\\ -\cos 2t & \sin 2t \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e^{2t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{3t} \end{bmatrix} $$ and so  (see https://www.lem.ma/ZN)  $$A^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} e^{2t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{3t} \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\sin 2t & \cos 2t\\ -\cos 2t & \sin 2t \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 \end{bmatrix} ^{-1}\\ = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-2t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-3t} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\sin 2t & -\cos 2t\\ \cos 2t & \sin 2t \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1/5 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/6 \end{bmatrix}$$
and now you can multiply the product out.

Answer (score 1):

A $2$x$2$ matrix has an inverse defined as follows:$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\underbrace{ad-bc}_{\text{determinant}}}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a\end{bmatrix}$$
It only exists if the determinant is non-zero.

Replace $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ by your expressions and turn the handle...

Comment: I believe there's an extra $^{-1}$ in your formula.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD - thanks for spotting my typo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint you may make everything in e ie $$\sin(x)=Ie^{ix},\cos(x)
=R(e^{ix})$$ then finding inverse can be done.